# Error in Ansible Playbook where Cloudwatch Agent Status is being checked

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-cloudwatch

can you help me? This is my ansible script:

```
---
- hosts: "{{host_list}}"
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - name: Check if Cloudwatch Agent is Installed Already
      command: service status amazon-cloudwatch-agent
      register: init_status_result
      ignore_errors: yes

    - debug:
        var: init_status_result.stderr
        verbosity: 4

    - name: Create Directory for Downloading Cloudwatch Agent zip
      file:
        path: /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-zip
        state: directory
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: '0755'
        recurse: no
      when: init_status_result.stderr is search ("For other actions, please try to use systemctl")
```

I have this error when attempting to run my playbook (I just want a way really to run through the playbook if the status check of the cloudwatch agent service is not found.):

````
user1@ansible01-infra-mgnt:~/.ansible/playbooks/cw_agent$ ansible-playbook -K -i /home/user1/.ansible/etc/hosts --extra-vars="host_list=11.22.33.44" install_cw_agent.yml
SUDO password:

PLAY [11.22.33.44] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [11.22.33.44]

TASK [Check if Cloudwatch Agent is Installed Already] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
 [WARNING]: Consider using the service module rather than running service.  If you need to use command because service is insufficient you can add warn=False to this command task or set command_warnings=False in ansible.cfg to get rid
of this message.

fatal: [11.22.33.44]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "service status amazon-cloudwatch-agent", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}
...ignoring

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [11.22.33.44]

TASK [Create Directory for Downloading Cloudwatch Agent zip] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [11.22.33.44]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'init_status_result.stderr is search (\"For other actions, please try to use systemctl\")' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if init_status_result.stderr is search (\"For other actions, please try to use systemctl\") %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): expected string or buffer\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/user1/.ansible/playbooks/cw_agent/install_cw_agent.yml': line 15, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: Create Directory for Downloading Cloudwatch Agent zip\n      ^ here\n"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/user1/.ansible/playbooks/cw_agent/install_cw_agent.retry

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
11.22.33.44                : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1 ```
````

Comment: Why is "No such file or directory" confusing? Do you have a binary named `service`, and is it on the `$PATH` of the user ansible is connected as? Have you tried taking ansible's advice and using the [`service:` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/service_module.html) to gain idempotency?

Comment: I am not sure if you marked my question down assuming you did by the tone of your response but thank you, your advice helped.

Answer (score -1):

Try shell module to check the service status instead of command module .

shell: “service status service_name”